# How do I delete album tags in multiple files?

Tags: rhythmbox

I have multiple tracks where I would like to delete the album entry. If I mark them in Rhythmbox and try to edit their tags, I can only change it to something else. If I leave the field empty, it does not change anything at all.

How can I void these fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend a tool made specially for tagging such as Easytag, most media players are limited in this regard. What you want can be done easily with Easytag, Install using Synaptic or software center.

or just type in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

Compact guide:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Music Brainz Picard is a great tag editor that can be of use.
sudo apt-get install picard
It can even use APE tags (those tags drove me nuts with rhythmbox for the longest).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [kid3-qt](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kid3-qt).

```
sudo apt-get install kid3-qt
```

If you use kde, install [kid3](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kid3) instead (without "-qt").

Advantages:

- Ease of use
- Edit ID3v1.1 tags
- Edit all ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 frames
- Convert between ID3v1.1, ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 tags
- Edit tags in MP3, Ogg/Vorbis, FLAC, MPC, MP4/AAC, MP2, Speex, TrueAudio, WavPack, WMA, WAV and AIFF files
- Edit tags of multiple files, e.g. the artist, album, year and genre of all files of an album typically have the same values and can be set together.
- Generate tags from filenames
- Generate filenames from tags
- Rename and create directories from tags
- Generate playlist files
- Automatically convert upper and lower case and replace strings
- Import from gnudb.org, TrackType.org, MusicBrainz, Discogs, Amazon and other sources of album data
- Export tags as CSV, HTML, playlists, Kover XML and in other formats

[Site: kid3.sourceforge.net](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/)

[Handbook Manual](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/kid3_en.html)

[image]

Comment: I think Ex Falso will do that too, but I would like to do that out of Rhythmbox directly ...

Comment: Well then it looks like a bug or a desired feature that would be sent to developers of the software (rhythmbox-devel@gnome.org).

Answer (score 1):

`id3v2` is the cli tool I use. Say for example that I want to delete all Album tags for all my Beyonce flac files then this does the trick:

```
id3v2 -A "" beyonce*.flac
```

If I want to call write the Album tag as say "Four" then it's as easy as:

```
id3v2 -A "Four" beyonce*.flac
```

Obviously the details like filenames vary and should be adjusted to suit.